# all image content appear in the div

Tags: html, image, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, slideshow

I have a slide show for the image, but the image does not appear entirely.
How can I solve this? I want to show the image no matter its height.
This image shows my problem. This is part of the image that appears in my slide show

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 85%;
}
.carousel,
.item,
.active {
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */

.fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slide1.jpg');"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slide2.jpg');"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slide3.jpg');"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>
</header>
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure what to include to turn this into a working snippet. Anyway, I suppose the answer could be to change `background-size:cover` into `background-size:contain`.

Comment: @MrLister  when i put it contain the image repeat x

Comment: thx i solve it by this     width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-position:center ;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;background-origin: content-box;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THANKS YOU

i solve the problem like this

```
 width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-position:center ;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;background-origin: content-box;
```